# Node.js debug is breaking in 1st line without giving proper error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my package.json

```
{
    "name":"chat",
    "version":"0.0.1",
    "private":"true",
    "dependencies":{
        "socket.io":"1.3.5",
        "express":"4.12.2"
    }
}
```

I did npm install and Folder node_modules is created and I can see express and socket.io

My app.js looks like this

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('send message', function(data){
        io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
    });
});
```

When I run `node debug app.js` , Its breaking in 1st line without any error.How to debug the correct error in node.js

Comment: Works for me:
`node debug app.js`
`< Debugger listening on port 5858`
`connecting to port 5858... ok`
`break in app.js:1`
`> 1 var express = require('express'),`
`2     app = express(),`
`3     server = require('http').createServer(app),`

Comment: then why do node app.js is staying blank ?

Comment: What else should it do? What happens if you open a browser and go to http://localhost:3000/ ?

Comment: I was testing in my server , htrp://pandatracking.com/socket/chat:3000 and pandatracking.com:3000 ..both not working

Comment: app.js and package json are in this folder socket/chat

Comment: Well, it's sending index.html. It is working, it just doesn't do much ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help :)  what does res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html'); do actually ?